# PHP5.5: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class

Tags: php, redeclare

since I upgraded from PHP 5.2 to 5.5 I get an error I don't understand by now.

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class sessionHandler in ... on line ...
```

Well before updating the PHP version this error didn't raise and redeclaring a class should be an error independent from PHP version as I guess. Further I always use require_once() which should help to avoid a mistake on that.

So just to make sure it doesn't be redeclared, I added a backtrace code block before that class declaration. So hopefully, I thought it would output twice, but I get only one backtrace output at all. Therefore it gets declared only once from my point of few.

Do I miss something? Any idea how to find the "real" issue?

Comment: What's the class name? Maybe the class name is already used in PHP.

Comment: I named it "sessionHandler"

Comment: Here, you go: http://php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandler.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class "SessionHandler" already exists in the namespace as it's a class in PHP - http://php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandler.php

Looks like the class was included in PHP 5.4 so it explains everything.

Try to think of some other name for the class or define a namespace.
If you create a namespace, something like..

```
namespace App;
class sessionHandler {
....
```

you won't get the error anymore but you will need to use App\sessionHandler whenever you're referring to your own class.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the very fast and correct solution.